# Is my server being used as a proxy or malicious requests?

Tags: ubuntu, security, apache-httpd, proxy

I have an Ubuntu, Apache, Passenger, and Rails 4 project on AWS EC2.

I am a full stack developer and am unfamiliar with the security and server side of my project.  This is my first time setting up Ubuntu and Apache, previously I have used Heroku.

Recently, my site was down because of "too many users" so when I checked my

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

I saw that I was getting non-stop GET requests from random IPs to my home page.  The requests have not stopped and continue to flood my server.

```
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:47.692152 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:47.692709 #11851]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.073504 #11851]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 54.252.254.204 at 2015-04-02 16:38:49 +0000
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.077260 #11851]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.084489 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.6ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.084799 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (6.2ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.085349 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.086550 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_google_analytics.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:49.087121 #11851]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.166665 #11851]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 107.23.255.12 at 2015-04-02 16:38:50 +0000
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.169943 #11851]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#home_page as */*
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.176601 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/_sign_up_modal.html.erb (1.4ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.176924 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/home_page.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
I, [2015-04-02T16:38:50.177425 #11851]  INFO -- :   Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/stripe-rails-0.3.1/app/views/stripe/_js.html.erb (0.1ms)
```

**Is my server being used as a proxy or is it being attacked?  How can I prevent this from continueing to happen?**

I attempted to use [this guide](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse) but as you will see from [my other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401312/log-shows-constant-get-requests-from-unknown-ips), I was unsuccessful and was only able to stop ALL requests including valid ones.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ec2-54-###-###-##.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /etc/projects/myapp/public

    <Directory /etc/projects/myapp/public>
            #Options FollowSymLinks
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Please help! I apologize if my terminology or the information provided is insufficient. I will eagerly supply more and better information with guidance.

Comment: Why are you enabling CGI for a `passenger` app? Can you post the lines you think are malicious? Are you using the AWS Elastic Load Balancer?

Comment: @jordanm Sorry I am new tot his so I am not sure why or how I am enabling CGI for passenger app.  I am now using Elastic Beanstalk, just EC2.  I added an example of 2 of the requests, as you can see, it is the same request repeating over and over again but each time with a new IP

Comment: Why do you think those simple `GET /` requests are malicious? The apache log should give more info such as the user agent and referer.

Comment: @jordanm I suppose they might not be malicious but they can't possibly be real traffic.  My site is very very low profile right now and the requests have been coming in consistently non stop...

Comment: They are most likely health checks from an Amazon ELB, but it's hard to tell. Both of those IPs are owned by Amazon.

Comment: @jordanm wow thank you!! I did not check the origin of the IPs...

Comment: Unless you configured your apache server to act as proxy, it is very  unlikely anyone can use it for a proxy. Out of the box, apache won't allow that. It is probably just random douchebag trying to flex on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard situation. The requests seem to match a malicious pattern, so your task is to block the IPs making malicious requests from your server.

These days there are all kinds of fancy hardware to do this. If you can't get that then you are down to manually creating firewall rules or apache rules to ignore or block requests from certain IPs.

For your server resource, it is better if the firewall blocks and not apache. You can use tcpdump to see all the IPs that are beating up your server. For example, something like:

tcpdump -nn port 80 | awk '{print$3}' | awk -F. '{print$1,$2,$3,$4}' | while read a b c d; do echo $a.$b.$c.$d >> newlist.txt; done

*note you can run the same thing for port 443

That will run until you stop it, and it will dump all the IPs hitting your server into a file. Then run something like:

cat newlist.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

Now you have a sorted list showing how many times each of those IPs hit your server in the time you let that first oneliner run. From that you decide how many requests seem abusive to you, by running several times you will pick out the offenders easily. Now you have to take those IPs and block them from your firewall.

This is a brutal and difficult way to defend yourself from DDOS. It won't work if someone is seriously attacking you, but in that case probably your server fell over already anyway.

There is no way to really stop them from attacking you without fancy network hardware, but with these principles you can at least defend yourself.. until you hit the limit of rules in your firewall at least. If it comes to that, block by ranges instead of individuals. Look at https://www.arin.net/ and google, you may find most of your hits coming from a certain area if you are lucky.. *cough* russia, china, eastern europe *cough* in that case consider blocking the entire region if it is degrading your server performance or you have valuable information that could be stolen from your website.

Comment: Here is something that can help you to know what IP blocks are assigned to which country, it will help you decide what to block: http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/

Comment: Also use grep to check your apache logs for POST commands. If someone has put a shell on your server, you may detect it like that. Look for string like: php?i=

Comment: When trying the run the tcpdump command in the root of my directory, I received an error "tcpdump: no suitable device found".  Can you please advice?  Thank you for your help @Baazigar

Comment: Check the tcpdump syntax, sometimes you may have to specify the interface that you want to use. You also may need root permissions. If you google on that error you saw you will probably find the solution.